# First 30 numbers of the fibonacci sequence with arrays

Tags: python, arrays

so I have to make a thing for school, but I can't figure it out. So I have to get the first 30 numbers of the Fibonacci sequence using arrays. The code should be simple, and mine looks something like this.

```
fib = [0, 1] * 15
for i in range(30):
    fib = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]
    print(fib)
```

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: `fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]`. what are *massives*?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist it's "array" in some languages

Comment: Please see [ask]

Comment: @trincot "avoid negative indexes". Why? Negative indexing is a very strong and useful feature for accessing Python lists

Comment: Honestly for the first 30 I'd use the naive recursive exponential time solution without any optimization, just to annoy the instructor :-D. Takes less than a second, so they can't complain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is fairly close with some modification, that is, the Fibonacci sequence starts with 1, 1 not 0, 1 and you need to store the result of each calculation for the next:

```
fib = [1]*30
for i in range(2, 30):
    fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]
    print(fib[i])
```

Comment: Then why does Wikipedia say ["The sequence commonly starts from 0 and 1"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)?

Comment: Why does [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=fibonacci&sort=&language=&go=Search) show it starting with 0, 1?

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=fibonacci+sequence) also starts it with 0, 1. How can they all be so incompetent?

Comment: I've always understood that the Fibonacci sequence starts with zero. You live and learn

Comment: Why does this code emit 2 as the first value in the sequence? (rhetorical)

Answer (score 0):

A generator is ideal for this exercise.

Try this:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

print(list(fibonacci(30)))
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use this:

```
fib = [0, 1]
for i in range(1,30):
    fib.append(fib[i] + fib[i-1])
print(fib)
```

The changes I have made is to append each fib number to the list. This is important for the list to update. Before you had nothing to change or add digits to the list. Then I just took the sum of the last number on the list (fib[i] not fib[i-1]) and the same with the second to last number on the list(fib[i-1] not fib[i-2])